# Multirow image caption

Tags: captions, multirow, italic

What is the best practice for Captions with a description of specific image parts where I want the title of the image in the first row and the description in italic and in second and third row (if the description doesn't fit in the second row)?

For now I used a tabular inside the caption, but this doesn't work with italic and it doesn't look clean.

What I have for now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption[Schematische Darstellung des Kathodenzerstäubungsprozesses]
{\tabular[t]{@{}l@{}}
Headline,\\
\newline\\
1:~DEscription, 2:~Deskription long long long long,\\
3:~Description
\endtabular}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i forgott i also want to reduce the space between the Headline and the first Description row

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. See if `\caption[Schematische Darstellung des Kathodenzerstäubungsprozesses]
{Headline,\newline\itshape
1:~Description, 2:~Deskription long long long long,\newline
3:~Description
}` is what you looking for.

Comment: no sadly not exactly, because now the description lines are not aligned with the Headline, but with the Figure 1:

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this (simple `hang` format for captions):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, format=hang]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption[Schematische Darstellung des Kathodenzerstäubungsprozesses]
{Headline,\smallskip \\
1:~Description, 2:~Deskription long long long long,\\
3:~Description}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You also might use this code, with the in-line lists of `enumitem`:

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
......
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption[Schematische Darstellung des Kathodenzerstäubungsprozesses]
{Headline,\smallskip \\
\begin{enumerate*}
\item Description,   \item Deskription long long long long, \newline
\item Description. 
\end{enumerate*} }
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks i played with just \\ bevor but i got something wrong because now it works with your example :)  i am very pleased

Comment: a i see you passed a third option to caption command nice